# function result type must be integer because of OUT parameters in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

In the below query when I execute it throws an error function result type must be `integer` because of `OUT` parameters.Pls anyone help me to overocme this issue.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funinsertupdateproduct(i_productid integer, t_productname text, t_productdesc text, i_brandid integer, i_varianceid integer, i_packsizeid integer, i_clientid integer, i_userid integer,out i_prodid integer )
  RETURNS void  AS
$BODY$ 
BEGIN 
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM  "product" WHERE product_id = i_productid) THEN
        UPDATE "product" SET "product_name" = t_productname,  "product_desc" = t_productdesc, "brand_id"=i_brandid,variance_id=i_varianceid,pack_size_id=i_packsizeid  WHERE product_id = i_productid;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO "product"("product_name", "product_desc", "create_by","client_id",variance_id,brand_id,pack_size_id ) VALUES (  t_productname, t_productdesc,i_userid,i_clientid,i_varianceid,i_brandid,i_packsizeid) returning product_id INTO i_prodid;

END IF;
  RETURN;
END;  
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION funinsertupdateproduct(integer, text, text, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer,integer) OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: "_When there are OUT or INOUT parameters, the RETURNS clause can be omitted. If present, it must agree with the result type implied by the output parameters: RECORD if there are multiple output parameters, or the same type as the single output parameter._" - [from the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html)

Answer (score 2):

Postgres functions take some getting used to.  In addition to being triggers and stored procedures, the way they handled returned values differs from other languages.

In essence, the `OUT` parameters represent the record that is being returned by the function.  There is no separate method of a returning a value, so the `void` is redundant . . . and, in fact, incompatible with the `OUT` parameters.

The solution is simple.  Just remove the `RETURNS` clause:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funinsertupdateproduct (
    i_productid integer,
    t_productname text,
    t_productdesc text,
    i_brandid integer,
    i_varianceid integer,
    i_packsizeid integer,
    i_clientid integer,
    i_userid integer,
    out i_prodid integer
) AS
$BODY$ 
. . .
```

Except for not defining `i_prodid`, this is equivalent to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funinsertupdateproduct (
    i_productid integer,
    t_productname text,
    t_productdesc text,
    i_brandid integer,
    i_varianceid integer,
    i_packsizeid integer,
    i_clientid integer,
    i_userid integer
) 
RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$ 
. . .
```

Answer (score 1):

> Generally we define function with return type and procedure with OUT
>   parameters.

If you want to define function, try with this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funinsertupdateproduct(i_productid integer, t_productname text, t_productdesc text, i_brandid integer, i_varianceid integer, i_packsizeid integer, i_clientid integer, i_userid integer )
  RETURNS integer  AS
$BODY$ 
declare
i_prodid integer;
BEGIN 
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM  "product" WHERE product_id = i_productid) THEN
        UPDATE "product" SET "product_name" = t_productname,  "product_desc" = t_productdesc, "brand_id"=i_brandid,variance_id=i_varianceid,pack_size_id=i_packsizeid  WHERE product_id = i_productid;
        i_prodid:=i_productid;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO "product"("product_name", "product_desc", "create_by","client_id",variance_id,brand_id,pack_size_id ) VALUES (  t_productname, t_productdesc,i_userid,i_clientid,i_varianceid,i_brandid,i_packsizeid) returning product_id INTO i_prodid;

END IF;
  RETURN i_prodid;
END;  
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Alternately you can use `PROCEDURE` with `out` parameters

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  funinsertupdateproduct(i_productid integer, t_productname text, t_productdesc text, i_brandid integer, i_varianceid integer, i_packsizeid integer, i_clientid integer, i_userid integer ,out i_prodid integer)
    AS

BEGIN 
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM  "product" WHERE product_id = i_productid) THEN
        UPDATE "product" SET "product_name" = t_productname,  "product_desc" = t_productdesc, "brand_id"=i_brandid,variance_id=i_varianceid,pack_size_id=i_packsizeid  WHERE product_id = i_productid;
        i_prodid:=i_productid;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO "product"("product_name", "product_desc", "create_by","client_id",variance_id,brand_id,pack_size_id ) VALUES (  t_productname, t_productdesc,i_userid,i_clientid,i_varianceid,i_brandid,i_packsizeid) returning product_id INTO i_prodid;

END IF;
END;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below. *The error below occurs in a [PL/pgSQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) and [SQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html):

> ERROR: function result type must be integer because of OUT parameters

Because, the types of an `OUT` parameter (`INTEGER`) and `RETURNS <type>` clause (`VOID`) are not the same in the PL/pgSQL function as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(OUT value INTEGER) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN                             -- ↑ Here      -- ↑ Here
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So, I set `INTEGER` to `RETURNS <type>` clause as shown below, then the error was solved:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(OUT value INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
BEGIN                                              -- ↑ Here
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or, I unset `RETURNS <type>` clause as shown below, then the error was solved:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(OUT value INTEGER) /* RETURNS VOID */ AS $$
BEGIN                                         -- ↑ Unset ↑
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```